# appscript determine how many rows from last checked checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I need to calculate in my script, how many rows there are since the last one with a checked checkbox in column 8. For instance in the image you see that every 6 empty rows there is a checked box in column 8. I need to check it every 6 empty ones.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRJE9.jpg

here's my function.

```
function addRow() {
  //Initialize variables
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

    var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var newData = (new Date());
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, 1, 11).insertCheckboxes();
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,2,1,6).check();

  // this works fine
  if(new Date().getDate() == 23){
      dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,7,1,1).check();
      dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,9,1,1).check();
      dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,11,1,1).check();
      dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,12,1,1).check();
  }

// here I need a new if statement to determine if it's more than 6 rows since the last checked one in column 8 and then check the checkboxes in columns 8 and 10

   if(rows_since_last_checkbox_checked_in_column_8 >= 6){
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,8,1,1).check();
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,10,1,1).check();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an option for your script to work.

First add the following lines to your function:

```
function addRow() {
  //Initialize variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var newData = (new Date());
  dataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
  dataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, 1, 11).insertCheckboxes();
  dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,2,1,6).check();

  // this works fine
  if(new Date().getDate() == 23){
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,7,1,1).check();
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,9,1,1).check();
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,11,1,1).check();
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,12,1,1).check();
  }

 
  if(countUncheckedRows(dataSheet, lastRow-1) > 6){//this is the new if you should add
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,8,1,1).check();
    dataSheet.getRange(lastRow,10,1,1).check();
  }
}
```

Second you add the helper function that counts the empty rows from bottom to top in column 8:

```
function countUncheckedRows(dataSheet, lastRow) {

  const valsCol8 = dataSheet.getRange(1,8,lastRow,1).getValues();
  let count = 0;

  for (var i = valsCol8.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

    if(valsCol8[i][0] === true){

      break;

    } else {

       count++

    }
  }

  return count;
}
```